# How to redirect to a generated PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am using mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf in order to dynamically generate a PDF in Laravel.

The PDF is getting generated fine, and I see it in my storage/app/public directory.

However, I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the trigger button, it not only generates the PDF, but then proceeds to either opens the PDF in the browser (if it is supported), or download it to their device.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$fileName = "fillable-".$user->unique_id.".pdf";
$pdf = new Pdf(public_path().'/pdfs/fillable.pdf');
$result = $pdf->fillForm([
   'form_field1' => 'John',
   'form_field2' => 'Smith',
   'form_field3' => '07-14-1983',
   'form_field4' => true
])->needAppearances()->saveAs(storage_path().'/app/public/pdfs/'.$fileName);

if ($result === false) {
   $error = $pdf->getError();
   echo $error;
} else {
   //This is where I want to redirect / download the PDF

   //*** Failed Method #1 ***
   //return response()->download($path); //This downloads a file – but, the PDF is "broken"


   //*** Failed Method #2 ***
   //return redirect(storage_path().'/app/public/pdfs/'.$fileName); //This just gives a 404 not found
}
```

As I mentioned – the PDF is getting generated, so it exists inside of the file system. I just need to know how I can redirect the user to it.

Anybody have any thoughts on how I could pull this off?

Comment: Would just `return redirect('/pdfs/'.$f`);` work?

Comment: @ChrisHaas That's kind of what I am doing under Failed Method #2. I think, because of Laravel's routing system, it sees that I am attempting to access a file path that doesn't have a registered route to it. But – even if I would make a route in my web.php file – I'm not sure how to make it load a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else that might have a similar question – this worked for me:

```
$fileName = "fillable-".$user->unique_id.".pdf";
$tempFilePath = storage_path()."/app/public/pdfs/".$fileName;
return response()->download($tempFilePath, $fileName)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```